# 404 error when doing workload anlysis using locust on OpenAI API (GPT.35)

Tags: python, openai-api, locust

I am trying to do some workload analysis on OpenAI GPT-3.5-TURBO using locust.

```py
from locust import HttpUser, between, task


class OpenAIUser(HttpUser):

    wait_time = between(1, 2)  # wait between 1 and 2 seconds
    host = "https://api.openai.com/"

    def on_start(self):

        self.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }

        self.data = {
            "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "role": "system",
                    "content": "You are a helpful story teller."
                },
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": "Tell me a 100 word story"
                }
            ]
        }

    @task
    def test_chat_completion(self):
        self.client.post(
            "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completion/",
            json=self.data,
            headers=self.headers
        )
```

I get this error:

```bash
POST /v1/chat/completion/: HTTPError('404 Client Error: Not Found for url: /v1/chat/completion/')
```

My script for Azure OpenAI workload analysis works fine with this exact same structure. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo error. Should be:

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
```

and not:

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completion/
```